# RegEx calculating number of distinct permutations

Tags: php, ruby, regex

So this is a bit unusual use of RegEx; I want to calculate number (or indicate infinite if suitable) of distinct strings that would be matched by a specific pattern.

For example let's consider `[a-zA-Z]` which would yield 52, `[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` which would yield 2652 (52+52×52−52×2; subtracting 52×2 for strings like `aa`,`MM` which are not distinct)  or `[a-zA-Z]+` which would be ∞.

Of course I'd like this mechanism to be able to deal with more complex regular expressions than that. I'm particularly interested in solutions for PHP and Ruby. Is this even possible?

Comment: Very interesting question, lots of uses if a suitable permutation calculator was created.  Would need a max string length and character table in order to allow `*` or `+`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're subtracting ``52*2`` for examples like ``aa``. The first letter is chosen from 52 characters. The second letter is chosen from 52 characters. This isn't a "choose" problem where you need to exclude an indistinguishable combination.

Comment: If you had access to the underlying [DFA](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#section_4) you could generate strings matching the regexp

Comment: This is an algorithm question. Implementing it in a particular language like PHP or Ruby is the next step, and should not be asked together in this question when you do not even know the algorithm, or whether such algorithm exists.

Comment: Is this entirely theoretical? Or is your application actually getting a regular expression string as input, and expected to count the possible strings that it would match?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't do the math too well - all the more reasons why I need to have a system to do it for me. @Kelvin: So far it is theoretical (although I have asked this as I have practical uses for this), however I will continue the search. If nothing pops up I may consider (attempting) to implement it (which I can use as part of my university course anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are used to match a given string by comparing it to a given pattern. Any given regex can match a large number of strings, the longer the regex the more strings it can match.

In my opinion, what you are after cannot be done with regular expressions. You can write a program which deconstructs the regular expression and tries to guess the amount of strings you could match. That being said however, the construction of such program will most likely not be trivial.

For instance, in your case, [a-zA-Z] will not only match `a` through `z` (and the same for the upper case variant), but it will also match any string which contains those letters, which basically is any string you can ever imagine which contains at least one of those letters.

Adding the `^` and `$` anchors might reduce the amount of hits, but then again, you will still have more than 48 since sometimes, you could also argue that `{EmptyString}a{EmptyString}` could also be matched by `^a$`, which makes the amount of possible results quite huge.

Comment: It's not something that could be done with the engine, but with the concept of regex, certainly.

Comment: @Orbling: Yes exactly, maybe attempt to create a Final State Machine and count the amount of cycles/nodes you can go through.

Comment: *Finite, but yes - it would be a useful engine to produce.  Permutations from a given regex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fairness, for my purpose, I would be limiting the strings with `^` and `&` anyway, and I'm not really interested in your case with empty strings. I have done some more research on this and exactly as you mentioned this is not a trivial problem - I have however found some sources talking about converting RegEx expression into Finite State Automaton - this might be a place to start for me.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this task, I think you would need a solution more complex than a regular expressions engine itself. Regular expressions engines merely "test" (and "capture", but the complexity of that is trivial), while in your task you wish either to test the entire discourse of potential inputs (of course, completely impractical), or *deduce* the number of potential inputs mathematically. But note how, in order to *deduce* the number of potential inputs, you inevitably end up having to step through more or less *the same steps that a regular expressions engine* does, except at each step asking, "Potential inputs for this atom?"

I'm not sure for what purpose you'd like such a counter, but if all you're trying to do is to compare the magnitudes of potential inputs of the two regexes, then I recommend using sampling methods, *i.e.* generating a large set of random strings, and counting how many of these are matched by each regex. (And this is going way over-the-top and is highly speculative, but since pure random strings aren't likely to exhibit patterns of grouping that natural language does, you may have to generate your samples using fractal techniques, *a la* Mandelbrot.)

Now, if you want to go the path of deductive counting *anyway*, here's two ideas that might help simplify the problem:

1. If you find a `*` or `+` (that is unescaped and not within a character class), then you know the answer is infinity. Same goes for `{M,}`. EDIT: Well, unless the quantifier is in an "impossible" piece of regex, e.g. `(.*(?=a)(?=b))`, where it has been asserted that the next character must be both "a" and "b"!
2. You can expand many expressions to alternation statements, so that whatever your final solution may be, it can ignore character classes and quantifiers altogether, only focusing on the number of atoms per alternation group (which can be multiplied together), *e.g.*

   1. Character classes like `[0-9a-f]` can be expanded to `0123456789abcdef` which in turn can be expanded to `(?:0|1|2|...|d|e|f)`.
   2. Finite quantifiers like `x?` (*a.k.a.* `x{0,1}`), `x{M,N}`, and `x{,N}` can be expanded to `(?:|x)`, `(?:x|xx|xxx|...)`, and so on.

Best of luck!

Comment: If you limit the use of quantifiers and thereby know the maximum length of a matching pattern, then you can generate all possible strings. You do not have to do sampling. You can get a decisive answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'm really looking for a deterministic algorithm as oppose to probabilistic one. It seems that I will have to attempt to create one - although it will probably fail. Your method of expanding `+`,`*` will certainly come in handy - lookarounds look particularly vicious tho.